# Laravel Queue suddenly stop service

Tags: laravel, queue

Laravel Queue:work(background task) suddenly stop in our server after certain time.we need to restart again to continue this service.how to fix this problem?

Comment: Which service are you using? [Supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#supervisor-configuration)? What do the logs show?

Comment: i used  "Supervisor".no log found

Comment: The file `/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log` does not exist at all?